TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - while reading json file data from s3 in Node 18
I am getting TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON error while reading json file content from s3 using node 18. I am using S3Client, GetObjectCommand of @aws-sdk/client-s3.
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
| property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
--- property 'socket' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at responseHook (/opt/wrapper.js:147:24)
at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation-aws-sdk/build/src/aws-sdk.js:149:61
at safeExecuteInTheMiddle (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation/build/src/utils.js:28:18)
at AwsInstrumentation._callUserResponseHook (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation-aws-sdk/build/src/aws-sdk.js:149:54)
at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation-aws-sdk/build/src/aws-sdk.js:269:34
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I am transforming s3 content into string using .transformToString('utf-8') method. Most probably transformToString() is throwing this error. Here is the code snippet.
const client = new S3Client({
            region
        });
const params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key
        };
const response = await client.send(new GetObjectCommand(params));
const body = await response.Body.transformToString('utf-8');

error screenshot

You can try using getObject which returns a promise. Hope that helps

const processFile = async () => {
   const client = new S3Client({ region });
   const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
   const response = await client.getObject(params).promise(); 
   return response.Body.toString('utf-8');
};

UPDATE:
based on the comment I using the wrong variable name client . I have updated the code above with the correction. However, if its not returning a promise (like due to the node / aws version your using maybe ?) then you can either use a third-parity library like promisify or rely on a callback function.
const processFile = async () => {
   const client = new S3Client({}); // you can replace {} with the region you are targeting
   const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
   const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
   const response = await client.send(command, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
   return response.Body.toString('utf-8');
};


UPDATE: Apologize, misread their documentation. I have updated the answer again which uses the callback func. If you are interested in looking over the documentation. Please feel free to review the resource below.
Resource:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_GetObject_section.html


Hi @TheoNeUpKID, I am getting this error TypeError: s3.getObject(...).promise is not a function

why you don't use S3Client instance. Is the second last line const response = await client.getObject(params).promise();  ?

used incorrect variable name but, I have updated the code and also provided another suggestion.

TypeError: client.getObject is not a function getObject is not function in ClientS3

Apologize, updated the callback solution and provided aws resource
